# Overcoming spatial bias in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, interpolation, spatial-statistics

I have a shapefile showing invasive plant locations but they mostly collected from more accessible places such as near roads or hiking trails.

Is there a method to correct this bias in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: What type of analysis are you doing with this data?

Comment: Many kinds of invasive plants do cluster near roads and trails, due to effects such as habitat edge effects; increased water availability from rain running off the road; and roads/trails acting as vectors for the spread of invasive plants (construction and maintenance activities spread invasive plant propagules, disturbance favors "weedy" plant species, long stretches of uniform habitat promote rapid spread). There's a strong correlation between places which are accessible for sampling, and places where invasive plants like to be.

Comment: @csk thank you for your comment. I will create a decay function for dispersion distance from urban lands. Any spatial bias might affect the function I will create. So, I need to handle the spatial bias even though indeed invasive plants found more near roads.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that there's no spatial bias; indeed there's strong spatial bias in invasive plant observations. Also strong bias towards species with pretty flowers, and within those species there's a strong temporal bias towards times of year when that species is in bloom. I also work with invasive plant sampling data, but I haven't done any modeling that would require this sort of bias correction. I'll be interested to see what answers this question generates. If you find an answer on your own, please consider "self-answering."

Comment: Oh! I see @csk. So far, I found this >> https://github.com/paigemiller/culex-SDM/wiki/Dealing-with-Spatial-Sampling-Bias-in-SDM so far. I will let you know if I can find the answer myself.